# How to run a Node.Js backend project from another developer?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Nodejs, normally when I make a project, I install the dependencies myself, and in order to run the project set something like this in the packaje.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  }
```

and then I just run my project with something like this `npm run dev`

But in a project made by someone else it doesn't seem to be that simple because it has the dependencies like this:

```
{
  "name": "proyecto API",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "proyecto Main Backend Repo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --harmony index.js",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --harmony index.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .js . --fix",
    "superuser": "node --harmony createSuperUser.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/proyecto-Network/lolagato"
  },
  "author": "gatito",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/proyecto-Network/lolagato/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/proyecto-Network/lolagato/erths",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.14.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongo-project": "^1.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Apparently here I can't just do `npm run dev` because as you can see in the packaje.json it comes out this:

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --harmony index.js"
```

So my questions are, how can I run this project on my PC and what does that say "cross-env" and --harmony mean?

I have to install all that that appears in the packaje.json?

Comment: You've already answered the question yourself :) Yes, you need to install all dependencies first (`npm i` or `npm ci`) in order to run the app...

Answer (score 0):

Just do,

```
npm install
```

This will install all the required dependencies. If you notice, in the `devDependencies` there is `cross-env` which is required for your `npm run dev`.

Once the dependencies are brought up, do `npm run dev`.

Or you could just do -

```
nodemon index.js
```

or

```
nodemon --harmony index.js
```

To see what happens.

`cross-env NODE_ENV=development` is just setting the environment variables. From their npm page -

**cross-env makes it so you can have a single command without worrying about setting or using the environment variable properly for the platform.**

Comment: i do it, i typed "npm install" and looks like it installed things, but after when i did "npm run dev" i get this error: npm ERR! Invalid name: "proyecto API"